# finding first 5 terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find first 5 terms of $a_n = 3(a_{n-1}+1)$ I believe this is fairly easy to do, I am unsure the proper format for this arithmetic sequence.  Should it be 3(an-1)+1 with the +1 being the distance.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you talking about a recurrence relation $a_n = 3 a_{n-1} + 1$? If yes, is any starting value given?

Answer (score 4):

If you talking about a recurrence relation $a_n = 3 (a_{n-1} + 1)$ and its given that $a_0=c$ then you can find:

$$a_1 = 3 (a_{1-1} + 1)= 3( a_{0} + 1)=3(c+1)=3c+3$$

and

$$a_2 = 3 (a_{2-1} + 1)=3 (a_{1} + 1)=3[(3c+3)+1]=9c+12$$

and

$$a_3 = 3 (a_{3-1} + 1)=3 (a_{2} + 1)=3[(9c+12)+1]=27c+39$$

Try to find $a_4$ and $a_5$.

**Edit:**

Q:  Given a recurrence relation $a_n = 3 (a_{n-1} + 1)$ and $a_1=1$. Find a closed formula for $a_n$.

Solution(more or less):

$$a_1=1$$
$$a_2=6$$
$$a_3=21$$
$$a_4=66$$
$$a_5=201$$

Now, notice that

$$a_2-a_1=5=3^0 \cdot5$$
$$a_3-a_2=15=3^1\cdot5$$
$$a_4-a_3=45=3^2\cdot5$$
$$a_5-a_4=135=3^3\cdot5$$

You can prove via mathematical induction that $a_n-a_{n-1}=3^{n-2}5$

The next thing we want to do is adding all the above equations:

$$(a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_4-a_3)+(a_5-a_4)+\cdots +(a_n-a_{n-1})=$$

$$3^0 \cdot5+3^1\cdot5+3^2\cdot5+3^3\cdot5+\cdots +3^{n-2}$$

$$=5(3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+\cdots+3^{n-2})$$

Do you see what to do next?

**Edit 2:**

$$(a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_4-a_3)+(a_5-a_4)+\cdots +(a_n-a_{n-1})=a_n-a_1=a_n-1$$

**Why** the above true?

And $3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+\cdots+3^{n-2}$ is sum of geometric series with $b_1=3^0=1$, $q=3$ and with $n-1$ terms (why?), the sum is given by

$$S_{n-1}=\frac{1-3^{n-1}}{1-3}=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-1)$$

Therefore,

$$(a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_4-a_3)+(a_5-a_4)+\cdots +(a_n-a_{n-1})=$$

$$3^0 \cdot5+3^1\cdot5+3^2\cdot5+3^3\cdot5+\cdots +3^{n-2}$$

$$=5(3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+\cdots+3^{n-2})$$

Becomes:

$$a_n-1=5\cdot \frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-1)$$

Or:

$$a_n=5\cdot \frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-1)+1$$

(Notice that $a_n$ is an integer for $n\geq 1$)

Comment: My apologies a1 =1

Comment: it is a recursively defined sequence

Comment: So if the distance is 1 and a1=1 then would this be correct?  I am thinking the common difference is 1.  a1=3(a1-1)+1 which is a1=3*(1-1)+1  3*0+1=0 and then a2=3(a2-1)=1 if a2=1 then the answer is still 1 and a3=3(a3-1)+1 I am confused as to starting point and actual formula.  thanks hopefully this makes it somewhat clearer

Comment: an=3(an−1+1) a1=1 is the actual question it is defined recursive.

Comment: No, no, no. 
You have some formula: $a_{n}=3(a_{n-1}+1)$ and its **given** that $a_1=1$. How to find $a_2$? Simple! Using the recurrence relation, we'll have $a_2=3(a_{2-1}+1)=3(a_{1}+1)$, but, again, $a_1=1$, thus -- $a_2=3(a_{1}+1)=3(1+1)=3\cdot 2=6$. Try find me $a_3$.

Comment: a3=3(a2+1)=3(6+1)=21

Comment: Correct! Well done! Now, $a_4$ and $a_5$.

Comment: a4=3(a4-1+1)=3(a3+1)=3(22)=66 a5=3(a5-1+1)=3(a4+1)=3(67)=201 a6=3(a6-1+1)=3(a5+1)=3(202)=606  What then is the common difference?  It does not look to be the same for each.

Comment: I am unsure what to do next.  It is not asked of me but I am curious, I was/am stuck on the common difference which maybe clear in your answer, although I am unable clearly define it